# CaptchaMVC show cross image first time

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, captcha

CaptchaMVC is not working on IE8 for first time

[image]

After clicking refresh link it rendered properly.

Again clicking the refresh the browser and getting the this cross image.

Here is my code:

```
@Html.Captcha("Refresh", "Enter the text shown in imag", 
    5, "Prove that you are not a robot",  false) 
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.CaptchaInputText)
```

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: any solution to this..?

Comment: Is there the below custom header in your web.config?

 `<add name="Referrer-Policy" value="no-referrer" />`